# How to stop vscode python terminal without deleting the log?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

when clicking "Run Python file in terminal" how do I stop the script? the only way that I found is by clicking the trashcan which deletes the log in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Python file is running in the terminal you can hit Ctrl-C to try and interrupt it.